# Fixed title inside a div taking the remaining size

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to have a div that contains three divs. The top and the bottom ones are fixed (but unknown in advance) size, while the middle one takes the remaining height of the parent div. In addition, the middle div has title and content, with a scrollbar on the content if overflowed.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65506332/2725810) post, here is what I have:

```css
#outer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

#inner_fixed {
    height: 150px;
    background-color: grey;
}

#inner_remaining {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    overflow-y: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
   <div id="inner_fixed">
      I have a fixed height
   </div>
   <div id="inner_remaining">
      <h1>
         I stay in place.
      </h1>
      <h2>
         I participate in scrolling.
      </h2>
      <h2>
         I participate in scrolling.
      </h2>
      <h2>
         I participate in scrolling.
      </h2>
      <h2>
         I participate in scrolling.
      </h2>
      <h2>
         I participate in scrolling.
      </h2>
   </div>
   <div id="inner_fixed">
      I have a fixed height
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I modify this, so that only the content of the middle div below the `<h1>` title would have the scrollbar? Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/057tdevw/1/).

Comment: *How can I modify this, so that only the content of the middle div scrolls?* Am i missing something, It already is scrollable, Did you try adding more content ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak Currently the whole middle div scrolls, whereas I need the title inside it to stay in place and the scrollbar apply only to the content below the title.

Comment: Oh you didn't specify that in the question, it's only in the title. Anyway you can use sticky position https://jsfiddle.net/ztxq0br4/

Comment: @ZohirSalak This is great, but I need the scrollbar to visually be only on the content below the title. I modified the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @ZohirSalak I now noticed that the reset `*,*:before,*:after {padding: 0; margin: 0;}` in your solution prevents the title from moving. Why is that the case?

Comment: Something like that? https://jsfiddle.net/4z9myaqg/

Comment: @JayNyxed Yes. Your were first, but with a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and added a `flex display` to your `#inner_remaining ID`. I also added `flex-direction: column;`

In order to get the scroll bar to be fixed within the scrollable content I added the following to your CSS:

```
* {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
div {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

For demonstration purposes, I added ***twice*** the amount of participating in scrolling `<h2>`'s

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#inner_fixed {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#inner_remaining {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

/* additions */
* {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

div {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner_fixed">
    I have a fixed height
  </div>
  <div id="inner_remaining">
    <h1>
    I stay in place.
    </h1>
    <div>
    <h2>
    I participate in scrolling.
    </h2>
    <h2>
    I participate in scrolling.
    </h2>
    <h2>
    I participate in scrolling.
    </h2>
    <h2>
    I participate in scrolling.
    </h2>
    <h2>
    I participate in scrolling.
    </h2>
    <h2>
    I participate in scrolling.
    </h2>
    <h2>
    I participate in scrolling.
    </h2>
    <h2>
    I participate in scrolling.
    </h2>
    <h2>
    I participate in scrolling.
    </h2>
    <h2>
    I participate in scrolling.
    </h2>
    <h2>
    I participate in scrolling.
    </h2>
    <h2>
    I participate in scrolling.
    </h2>
    <h2>
    I participate in scrolling.
    </h2>
    <h2>
    I participate in scrolling.
    </h2>
    <h2>
    I participate in scrolling.
    </h2>
    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="inner_fixed">
    I have a fixed height
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to be working even without `* {flex-grow: 1;}`